# cgi waiting page

Tags: html, cgi

how I can do something like that:
http://online.vodafone.co.uk/en_GB/assets/static/ipi_please_wait.gif
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript spinning wait hourglass-type thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41162/javascript-spinning-wait-hourglass-type-thing)

Comment: This question shows no effort at all. It will likely get voted down and closed. Please do some research, try some things, then ask a very specific, focused question with code examples.

Comment: @user751189 - Welcome to stackoverflow. A question like this one has already been asked, so your questions may be closed. If that happens, just follow the links to that other question, and hopefully it will have the information you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Go to http://www.ajaxload.info/ and generate your own ajax loader :)

Comment: Ok, so the answer is a little tongue-in-cheek.

Comment: So you don't blow all your time on one load'er, you can always check out http://www.preloaders.net/en/3d.  Some funky ones there.

Comment: Thanks. However i am running a cgi script on the background and is taking time to upload the results on the webpage. I would like to include script to show that the process is loading until the results are displayed on the page.

Comment: @user751189: That is possible, but make a new question and explain better what you have, what you want, what you tried, what works and what doesn't. Try to use correct English, and people will help you. A quick, dirty question without enough effort in it, will be closed ;)